# Almacenar resultados de procedimiento almacenado en tabla temporal

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Transfondo**

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en una base de datos en SQL Server 2012<sup>1</sup> que obtiene el promedio de algunos valores. Este procedimiento almacenado recibe como parámetros dos (2) valores de tipo int.

Ejemplo:

- IdFuncionario
- IdProceso

<sup>1</sup> Es la versión del gestor de base de datos que tengo en el equipo de desarrollo, pero es posible que esta base de datos esté instalada en una versión diferente.

---

**Problema**

Ya que el procedimiento almacenado también debe permitir obtener el promedio de todos los funcionarios, quisiera crear un nuevo procedimiento para ejecutarlo de esta manera:

*Código de consulta de prueba:*

```
-- Crear tabla temporal. Código adaptado de 
-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/654418/4092887
CREATE TABLE #tmpBus
(
   IDFUNCIONARIO NUMERIC (12, 0),
   NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
   CAL_1 FLOAT,
   CAL_2 FLOAT
);

-- Usando CTE "Common Table Expressions", recorrer la tabla "Funcionarios"
-- e invocar el procedimiento almacenado para ir guardando los resultados
-- en la tabla temporal "#tmpBus".
WITH CTE_func
AS
(
    SELECT FUNC.IdFuncionario, FUNC.Nombre, 1 AS IdProceso
    FROM Funcionario AS FUNC
)
SELECT temp.Nombre, EXEC SP_PromedioReporte temp.IdFuncionario, temp.IdProceso
FROM CTE_func AS temp

-- Retornar los valores almacenados en la tabla temporal.
SELECT *
FROM #tmpBus
```

Donde `SP_PromedioReporte` es el procedimiento almenado que calcula el promedio según el empleado y proceso especificado; devolviendo dos columnas:

```
---------------------------
| Promedio 1 | Promedio 2 |
---------------------------
```

Los resultados que espero obtener son similares a esta tabla:

```
---------------------------------------
| Nombre    | Promedio 1 | Promedio 2 |
---------------------------------------
|Alfonso    | 10         | 85         |
---------------------------------------
|María      | 12         | 38         |
---------------------------------------
|Jaime      | 16         | 63         |
---------------------------------------
|Rodrigo    | 20         | 69         |
---------------------------------------
|Laura      | 18         | 49         |
---------------------------------------
```

---

Buscando en otras preguntas y respuestas en Stack Overflow, me encontrado [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/654418/4092887) donde básicamente se crea una tabla temporal para almacenar los resultados del procedimiento almacenado, pero no logro ajustar la consulta para que, *al recorrer todos los funcionarios (de la tabla Funcionarios)*, se ejecute y se guarde en la tabla temporal.

Los errores que tengo son de sintaxis y reconozco que no tengo idea de cómo puedo realizar esta funcionalidad.

¿Cómo puedo generar un procedimiento almacenado que a su vez llame a otro procedimiento almacenado "en este caso, a `SP_PromedioReporte`" según lo explico en esta pregunta? ver *código de consulta de prueba:*.

NOTA: Para este caso, estoy buscando una solución puramente en SQL Server, ya que, por lógica, podría consultar primero la tabla "Funcionarios" y hacer un ciclo para ir llamando al procedimiento almacenado y procesar todo "por back-end", sin embargo, en el proyecto en el que estoy involucrado, se busca que toda la lógica se aplique en procedimientos almacenados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible mandar llamar a un procedimiento almacenado directamente desde una consulta, pero lo que sí puedes hacer es mandarlo llamar a través de una función, es decir, en lugar de que `SP_PromedioReporte` sea un procedimiento almacenado, éste sea una función, para lo cual quedaría algo como esto:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_PromedioReporte (@IdFuncionario INT, @IdProceso INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,6)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultado DECIMAL(18,6)

    --Código de ejemplo para regresar un resultado, yo puse una división para simular el valor de retorno
    --Aquí va la lógica de lo que anteriormente era un Stored Procedure
    SET @resultado = @IdFuncionario / @IdProceso

    RETURN @Resultado
END
```

Con esto, ya lo podrás mandar llamar en tu consulta directamente con `dbo.FN_PromedioReporte(temp.IdFuncionario, temp.IdProceso)`:

```
....
SELECT temp.Nombre, dbo.FN_PromedioReporte(temp.IdFuncionario, temp.IdProceso)
FROM CTE_func AS temp
....
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración](http://rextester.com/BDVRLW42552)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Al menos hasta dónde yo sé la única forma de resolverlo es mediante un cursor, no es lo ideal y siempre habría que buscar mejores alternativas, pero bueno... funciona. Tu ejemplo quedaría algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpBus
(
   IDFUNCIONARIO NUMERIC (12, 0),
   NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
   CAL_1 FLOAT,
   CAL_2 FLOAT
)

DECLARE _C CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR 
SELECT  IdFuncionario, 
        1 AS IdProceso
        FROM Funcionario 

DECLARE @IdFuncionario  NUMERIC (12, 0)
DECLARE @IdProceso  NUMERIC (12, 0)

OPEN _C

FETCH NEXT FROM _C INTO @IdFuncionario, @IdProceso
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tmpBus(IDFUNCIONARIO, NOMBRE, CAL_1, CAL_2) 
        EXEC SP_PromedioReporte @IdFuncionario, @IdProceso
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM _C INTO @IdFuncionario, @IdProceso
END

CLOSE _C
DEALLOCATE _C

SELECT  *
    FROM #tmpBus
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, tengo una pregunta, ¿el resultado del promedio en qué parte se estaría mostrando? es decir, ejecutas el procedimiento para obtenerlo pero, después de ahí sigue quedando al *aire esa información*.

Comment: Según lo que entendí en tu consulta es SP_PromedioReporte  el que calcula el promedio, el resultado devuelto lo salvamos en #tmpBus, luego simplemente hacemos un SELECT de esta tabla.