# Como llamar un stored procedure dentro de otro

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

como puedo solucionar este problema, estoy intentando llamar un stored procedure dentro de otro, este es el codigo que he hecho hasta el momento, en la primera imagen me funciona el stored procedure(SP_SELECTINVENTARIO) en el segundo es el problema que tengo, como puedo realizar el stored procedure.

este es el codigo

```
-- SELECCIONAR INVENTARIO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SELECTINVENTARIO
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT C.NAMECLIENTE AS NOMBREPROYECTO,C.NUMPARTE,C.DESCRIPTIONSPANISH,
C.FECHAINGRESO,S.FECHA AS FECHASALIDA,
C.CANTIDAD AS MATERIALENTRADA,S.CANTIDADMATERIAL AS MATERIALSALIDA,
C.CANTIDAD-S.CANTIDADMATERIAL AS FISICOALMACEN 
FROM CATALOGO C , SALIDAMATERIAL S WHERE C.ID_PARTENTRADA = S.ID_PARTNTRADA;
END 
GO

exec SP_SELECTINVENTARIO

CREATE PROCEDURE BUSCA_INVENTARIO
@NOMBREPROYECTO VARCHAR(100),
@NUMPARTE VARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN
EXEC SP_SELECTINVENTARIO;

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT * FROM SP_SELECTINVENTARIO WHERE NAMECLIENTE LIKE '%' + @NOMBREPROYECTO 
+ '%' OR NUMPARTE LIKE '%' + @NUMPARTE + '%'
END 
GO
```

resultado del primer stored procedure

[image: prueba]

Comment: Colocando el procedimiento `SP_SELECTINVENTARIO` en una función. Mira esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63680/78).

Comment: @sstan estoy tratando de llamar los datos que me arroja el stored procedure y al segundo intento buscarlo por nombre de proyecto o numero de parte

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pesar de que un SP tiene la habilidad de ejecutar una consulta y devolverte resultados, no es posible usar un SP en la claúsula `FROM` de una consulta, como si fuera una tabla:

```
SELECT * FROM SP_SELECTINVENTARIO ...
```

Si tu SP aceptara parámetros, te recomendaría convertirlo a un *table-valued function*. Pero siendo que tu SP ni siquiera necesita parámetros y simplemente es una forma de encapsular una consulta, lo más apropiado es de definirla como un *view*:

```
create view VW_SELECTINVENTARIO AS
SELECT C.NAMECLIENTE AS NOMBREPROYECTO,C.NUMPARTE,C.DESCRIPTIONSPANISH,
C.FECHAINGRESO,S.FECHA AS FECHASALIDA,
C.CANTIDAD AS MATERIALENTRADA,S.CANTIDADMATERIAL AS MATERIALSALIDA,
C.CANTIDAD-S.CANTIDADMATERIAL AS FISICOALMACEN 
FROM CATALOGO C , SALIDAMATERIAL S WHERE C.ID_PARTENTRADA = S.ID_PARTNTRADA;
go
```

Allí sí puedes usarlo dentro de tu otro SP agregándole filtros adicionales:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BUSCA_INVENTARIO
@NOMBREPROYECTO VARCHAR(100),
@NUMPARTE VARCHAR(100)
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SELECT * FROM VW_SELECTINVENTARIO WHERE NOMBREPROYECTO LIKE '%' + @NOMBREPROYECTO 
+ '%' OR NUMPARTE LIKE '%' + @NUMPARTE + '%'
END 
GO
```